# Powerbeats3 Bluetooth Mic Not Working

Tags: release-hera, bluetooth, audio

I am able to get my Powerbeats3 to work as a Bluetooth A2DP sync, however I can not get the mic or even the HFP profile to work. I am running 5.1 Hera.

Comment: Using Blueman I am able to switch the profile between A2DP and Off but it throws the error "Failed to change profile to headset_head_unit" when trying to change to HFP.